# Django Generic Template URL Reference

Tags: django, django-views

I am building an application where I will have 10 Detailed views that are the same information(name/slug) but referencing different models.  Within that view I am using the name to show a manytomany relation.

I want to use a single template file for each view.  The problem I am having is I have a  breadcrumb I want to reference back to the current detailed views index.

Is there a way to via get_context or something to provide the URL via its name, to pass to the template?  So in the generic_detail template I want to pass url names as variables.

**models.py**

```
class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    datastore = models.ForeignKey('Datastore', default=DEFAULT_VALUE)

class Datastore(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

**views.py**

```
class DatastoreIndexView(ListView):
   template_name = 'inventory/generic_index.html'
   model = Datastore


class DatastoreDetailView(DetailView):
   template_name = 'inventory/generic_detail.html'
   model = Datastore
   context_object_name = 'object'
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^datastore/$, DatastoreIndexView.as_vew(), name="datastore_index")
url(r'^datastore/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$,  DatastoreDetailView.as_vew(), name="datastore_detail")
```

**generic_detail.html**

```
{% block breadcrumbs %}
<ol class="nav  breadcrumb--path">
  <li class="milli"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
  <li class="milli"><a href=" Variable for URL for object.index ">{{ object.parent }}</a></li>
  <li class="milli">{{ object.name }}</li>
</ol>
{%  endblock breadcrumbs %}
```

Comment: You have to post the code you have currently, to show where you're stuck, then you may get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that you can use *urlresolvers.reverse* to call the view by name.

**views.py**

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DatastoreDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['index_view'] = reverse('datastore_index')
        return context
```